# browser REALLY slow in updating changes i html

Tags: jquery, localhost

I'm using wamp, developing using php, jquery with including html-files on events. But when i do changes in an included html-document, the browser doesn't get the changes. Restarting wamp, aptana or the browser won't help. When I manually go into the www folder, I can see the changes. Only when I open everything like the next day, the updates are there. Very frustrating!

Comment: Have you tried clearing your browser's cache?

Comment: Have your tried `Ctrl+F5` for reload? This circumvents the cache. Also consider deleting browser cache completely. You could set `Expires` headers in your apache (eg. in .htaccess file) to some date in the past to force the browser to take the actual version from server.

Answer (score 2):

A few solutions:

1. Use [`header()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) method of PHP in your document to set a page expiration date
   `header('Expires: Fri, 1 Aug 1986 11:31:41 GMT');`
2. Use the [`<meta>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/meta) portion of the html document to set caching
   `<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">`
3. Use the `<meta>` portion to set expiration of the page
   `<META HTTP-EQUIV="EXPIRES"
   CONTENT="Fri, 1 Aug 1986 11:31:41 GMT">`
4. Use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> when you visit the page and force a hard refresh.

Assuming it is just your browser caching information.

Comment: I rarely need to do more than #4. Option key + refresh does the same on the Mac.

Answer (score 1):

The best development environment I've found is Chrome's incognito mode.

Ctrl+Shift+N from a chrome window will open a new window that doesn't have caching, cookies, or history.